# Convert GUID array to int array

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using linq query to create my collection based on it's id which is a guid.I've an item which can be associated to 1 or more products.What I need is to show all the productnames associated to that item and other datas like name,summary,date aswell.My issue here is when i try to use the variable i which is a guid in my array it throws error that Guid cannot be converted to int.I'm very sure that I've to convert my Guid array to int array but not sure how to implement it. below is my code.

```
       foreach( Guid  i in itemid)  
       {           


          var vals = from r in datacontext.ItemTable_s where r.itemID == i select r;

            ItemTable_s[] tempdata = vals.ToArray<.ItemTable_s>();       

            Facet[] ftemp= new Facet[tempdata.Length]; 

   ItemImage image = null;
   string s1="";



      for (int iv = 0; iv < tempdata.Length; iv++)
          {
          s1 += tempdata[i].productname + "\n";

          }

           ftemp[3] = new facet("Productname",facettype.text,s1);   
          collection.AddItem( tempdata[i].ItemName, null, null,
                               new ItemImage(new Uri(-tempdata[i].location))
                                                                );




   }
```

In my above code tempdata[i] is where i get error msg saying guid cannot be converted to int implicitly.How do i fix this is there any other better approach?

Comment: Whats a Facet and what is the constructor Arguments.
It seems more logical to me that the 3 parameter for the Facet class is an Integer and not a GUID

Comment: You can convert Guids into ints but it is very ugly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518684/convert-guid-to-int

Comment: my variable i is a GUID as per my foreach loop.my facet are all string but my tempdata is an array of my items guid's.

Comment: It's complaining because an array's `Count` is a method, not a property. Use `items.Length`, or actually execute the method by using `items.Count()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(A GUID is 128 bits, so it cannot safely be converted into a 32-bit integer.)

A better option might be to use a `Dictionary<Guid, ItemTable_s>`.  Then you can still use GUIDs to index it.

```
var tempdata = new Dictionary<Guid, ItemTable_s>;
foreach(var anItem in datacontext.ItemTable_s)
{
    tempdata.Add(anItem.ItemID, anItem);
}
```

Then the line that's currently raising an exception (`s1 += tempdata[i].productname + "\n";`) should work as-is.

This will also make your `itemid` array unnecessary.   Alternatively you could keep the two arrays you're using.  Then you would have to change that line to:

```
s1 += tempdata[itemid.IndexOf(i)].productname + "\n";
```

It looks like that is what you were intending to do.  But that will be much slower than using a dictionary. It means you'll be doing a sequential search of the `itemid` array every time you need to figure out where an entry is in `tempdata`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.How do i declare the tempdata in an array.how do i handle   foreach( Guid  i in itemid)  
       {           


          var vals = from r in datacontext.ItemTable_s where r.itemID == i select r;

            ItemTable_s[] tempdata = vals.ToArray<.ItemTable_s>();

Answer (score 2):

Change your logic. Instead of using a foreach, use an int for statement. Then access the itemid's from the array. Something like this:Something like this:

```
    for( int i=0; i<items.Count; i++)
{
    ...
    var vals = from r in datacontext.ItemTable_s where r.itemID == itemid[i] select r;
    ...
    s1 += tempdata[i].productname + "\n";
}
```

Didn't try the code, but I hope you'll get the idea...

Comment: i tried your code but it throws error on i<items.count saying Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and method 'group'.Any help?

Answer (score 0):

A GUID looks like this

7c9e6679-7425-40de-944b-e07fc1f90ae7

As you can see there is not an Int Representation of that character. your Facet Constructor would need to take a GUID instead of an int.

Comment: but y when i try to use tempdata[i].description shows error saying i cannot be converted to int from guid? Any suggestions.I just don't want to get into convertions if it's not necessary.